# Cordova Plugin for Launch App from Browser using URL Schemas

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

We can launch apps from browser in iOS and Android both.. And it is implemented using URL schemas.

Wnat to know is there any Cordova Plugin to handle above scenario..?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin) ?

(url : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin)

It is pretty straight forward and is based on defining custom schema.

I am using cordova build so the only thing I had to do was add

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp">
  <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="MagicButtonApp" />
</gap:plugin>
```

and then open a browser and type in `MagicButtonApp://` to launch my application. Obviously in a real world scenario this would be a link on a site!

Comment: Hi, and thank you for this helpfull answer. I would like to ask, is there a way to capture regular URLs and have them launch my app ? Because I saw that many times. For example opening an url to the 9gag.com website will ask me if I want to open it in Chrome or in 9GAG app. Thanks again.