# Open a Cordova mobile application from a link in a website

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, youtube

I have created an application which is similar to the website. When a user visits the website on their iOS or Android device I want to output a link which lets them open or download the application.

For example when you visit Youtube on your mobile device a popup appears saying Open this page in "YouTube":

[image]
If you click this popup it opens the YouTube app on my phone.

I want to do this with my website and application. The app is created using Cordova. Does anyone know how to do this? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095638/iphone-apps-can-i-open-an-app-from-a-link-in-a-website) which is similar, but it is for native iOS. I need a cross platform Cordova solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent

Comment: Cheers @sanatshukla I will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is looking for a similar solution in the future.

As @sanat shukla mentioned in the comments there is a plugin created by EddyVebruggen which allows you to do this:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: This plugin is very useful, I have used it in a production project before.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="www.myapp.com" android:scheme="MyApp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Yeah I found a few solutions native, struggling to find one Cordova specific. Thanks though!

Comment: @smj2393 use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977451/cordova-plugin-for-launch-app-from-browser-using-url-schemas